# Encountered a error while pip install rasterio

Tags: python, pip, rasterio

I am working on windows 10 and encountered an error while executing pip install rasterio in anaconda prompt.

```
(base) C:\Users\skywalker>pip install rasterio
Collecting rasterio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/84/be5689470a73f5f8988cf44b81cb3493ebb8abbbebb69768c8fc86fccdd5/rasterio-1.0.24.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More information is available in the README.
    ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SKYWAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iyhe142u\rasterio\
```

Comment: Why not post an actual solution?

Comment: @Shawn Updating conda worked for me. You could also try to install a specific version of rasterio using conda forge.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by following these steps:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install GDAL-1.11.2-cp27-none-win32.whl
pip install rasterio-0.24.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Found in [official docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using anaconda, you can do :

```
conda install -c conda-forge <package-name>
```

In my opinion, it is always better to use anaconda on windows.